# Using regex with run-parts on Alpine 3.9

Tags: regex, alpine-linux

I'm creating a Docker image `FROM alpine:3.9.2` and I need to run `run-parts`. I used the script below in the past on `ubuntu:16.04` without problems.

```
 run-parts --verbose --regex '\.sh$' "$DIR"
```

However, this time around, I get errors on the options I pass to it. I.e.

> run-parts: unrecognized option: verbose
>
> run-parts: unrecognized option: regex

From my understading Alpine 3.9.2 uses `run-parts 4.8.6` https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/run-parts which should come from the `debianutils` https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debianutils/run-parts.8.en.html and supports both `verbose` and `regex`.

Am I missing anything here?

how can I run all the files ending with `.sh` on Alpine 3.9.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very cut version of `run-parts` in alpine image by default. It is busybox one:

```
/ # which run-parts
/bin/run-parts
/ # run-parts --help
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: run-parts [-a ARG]... [-u UMASK] [--reverse] [--test] [--exit-on-error] DIRECTORY

Run a bunch of scripts in DIRECTORY

    -a ARG      Pass ARG as argument to scripts
    -u UMASK    Set UMASK before running scripts
    --reverse   Reverse execution order
    --test      Dry run
    --exit-on-error Exit if a script exits with non-zero
```

It can only run a bunch of scripts in directory.

If you want to use uncut [run-parts](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86_64/run-parts) from the debianutils package, you need to install it first to alpine image:

```
/ # apk add --no-cache run-parts
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing run-parts (4.8.6-r0)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 15 packages
```

Now, there is a full version of `run-parts` in alpine instance:

```
/ # which run-parts
/usr/bin/run-parts
/ # run-parts --help
Usage: run-parts [OPTION]... DIRECTORY
      --test          print script names which would run, but don't run them.
      --list          print names of all valid files (can not be used with
                      --test)
  -v, --verbose       print script names before running them.
      --report        print script names if they produce output.
      --reverse       reverse execution order of scripts.
      --exit-on-error exit as soon as a script returns with a non-zero exit
                      code.
      --lsbsysinit    validate filenames based on LSB sysinit specs.
      --new-session   run each script in a separate process session
      --regex=PATTERN validate filenames based on POSIX ERE pattern PATTERN.
  -u, --umask=UMASK   sets umask to UMASK (octal), default is 022.
  -a, --arg=ARGUMENT  pass ARGUMENT to scripts, use once for each argument.
  -V, --version       output version information and exit.
  -h, --help          display this help and exit.
```

Comment: Thank for your help.